# Adding transition effects to a gif or short video

Tags: photoshop-effects, gif, adobe-after-effects, video

I'm pretty new to creating GIFs and video effects so please excuse my ignorance. I searched for 2-3 hours for a simple tutorial on this but it is difficult to find.

Would anyone know how I can do this simple task: I have an image divided into 4 sections. I want each section to "fly in" from outside the screen into view, one right after the other until all 4 pieces are there. I don't want the video to loop.

I have the entire Adobe suite so I can use anything they have. I started creating it in Photoshop as a GIF and I assumed I could probably add the "Fly in" effect to each section of the image but it seems Photoshop doesn't have such capabilities for GIFs.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please take a look around at [tour], and read through [ask] and [answer] a question to understand our community, what makes a good question here, and how to best frame a query. You *may* find some folks feeling your question is overly broad as initially posted - it *might* help to add more detail about what you've tried, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in Photoshop is making a **Video Timeline Animation**

[image: animation]

- Open the **Timeline Panel** and click the **Create Video Timeline** button

  [image: Convert Video Timeline]
- Put all the illustration objects at the origin position
- At the timeline panel, expand the timeline of one of the objects to see the options
- With the playhead at frame 0, click the Position chronometer icon to add a keyframe; a yellow diamond will appear at the timeline.
- Place the playhead at the last frame and add another position keyframe
- Move the object to the final position
- Play the animation
- Repeat with all the objects

[image]

<sub>*Note: This illustration is made with vector objects, the animation is built at the **vector mask position***</sub>

To make the animation one after the other, the order of appearance of the objects in the timeline must be staggered after each animation, as is shown in the lower image:

[image: timeline]

Comment: Hi there, thank you sooo much Danielillo! This was exactly what I needed to know. Very helpful! Have a great day.